# Storing Windows SDKs in source control?

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, sdk, msbuild, build-automation

The question is at the end - let me start by posing the context:

One of the problem we are facing at work when using *Visual Studio* is to make sure that everybody on the team is using the same version of the SDKs.

A typical problem would be to have somebody use a different *Direct X SDK* version resulting in a different behavior of the code, or somebody upgrading to a more recent Platform/Windows SDK in order to use some new API and having the code fail on other's programmers machines if they still use the previous version.

A way we used to solve the issue for other middleware has been to put the whole set of libraries, include files, tool chains, etc... in our source control system, and have our projects to use these so nobody has to install anything.
We also managed to do that with earlier version of the Direct X SDK, but we always ran into issues with the Windows/Platform SDK due to the close links between the SDK and the toolchain.

Since we now have to support both VS2010 and VS2012, and have to support from Windows XP to Windows 8 targets, we have to support **v100**, **v110** and **v110_xp** toolsets.

This means that we need all the associated compilers and the corresponding SDKs, both on our developer machines and build systems: This is getting ridiculously costly to maintain, specially considering that random windows updates and .net framework releases routinely tend to break msbuild.

So the question is:

- Is it possible to have Visual Studio to use non installed toolsets and SDK and instead having it use whatever is available in some folder out of the normal VS installation locations?
- Bonus question: If it is doable, is it possible to do that without having to change any locally installed configuration file on the machine - ie: Have all that in the solution/project or property sheets - so if we change the structure on the source control system we don't have to update every single machine?

Thanks :)

Comment: I would vouch for the VM (build server) way. Alternatively, ghost installation images. (IMO what you're describing is, in a way, the UNIX world, and sadly Microsoft doesn't fit that picture too well)

Comment: Yes to both questions, however it's more a hack than trivial operation. It something you can setup on the build machine. In any case you should branch this out and roll it to the dev branch when ready for use.

Comment: I agree with @sehe that you should try to build standard VMs and force the developers to use the same environment. This is a strict process that everyone should follow unless someone wants to break the build and hurt anyone else. If someone does need to use a newer SDK, build a new VM image for him/her, and ask to check in to an isolate branch. Once the time is right, everyone should upgrade to that new VM image. If you make good management, you don't need to check in SDKs to source control, as that's not the solution.

Comment: @LexLi To be fair, I discussed this with Mickaël in chat and [it turned out to be unfeasible for the actual dev stations because of the need for direct GPU access](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=8873817#8873817). (It is still an option for build servers)

Comment: There are indeed solution (for Windows) to provide direct GPU access, the so called boot-to-VHD, http://blogs.technet.com/b/haroldwong/archive/2012/08/18/how-to-create-windows-8-vhd-for-boot-to-vhd-using-simple-easy-to-follow-steps.aspx. Both Windows 7 and 8 supports this. It only makes use of virtualized hard disk and is quite similar to dual boot. You might evaluate if that is enough for your team.

Comment: @LexLi: So the idea would be to have pre-built configurations with the correct version of visual studio, sdks, etc... update these master configurations, and have everybody use that, booting on them like if it was the actual machine OS ?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds too complicated, given how complex some of these tool installations are. I would solve this problem by investing in some PowerShell scripts that look at the installed tools and tool paths and "police" the installations. It would be relatively easy to check for installed versions of everything, including patches and updates. You can run those nightly, or as part of a build. Also, you can compare aspects of different installations, such as the tool versions installed on a developer box with your build server.

This would give you 90% of the value for 10% of the pain.

Answer (score 0):

The problems you describe are not solved with your approach. What you actually need is a build server and a definition of done including using binaries built with the build server. You also need a test suite as part of the build definition with some invariants related to the build environment used.